# how to average rows based on two duplicated rows?

Tags: r, duplicates, average

I have 2000 rows with some duplicates, I would like to average the rows based on duplicates.

```
Site  Location Line    Band1
Cal   BC04     BC04A   130
Cal   BC04     BC04B   131
Cal   BC04     BC04C   129
```

I have tried:

```
 bind_cols(
    FC %>% distinct(site) %>% .[,-Band1],  # pull out columns we aren't      aggregating
  FC[,c(1, Band1)] %>% group_by(Band1) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% .[,-1]  # aggregate other columns
)
```

So ideally, I would like to result in:

```
Site  Location Line    Band1
Cal   BC04     BC04A   130
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Site) %>%
 filter(n() > 1) %>%
 mutate(Band1 = mean(Band1)) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup()

  Site  Location Line  Band1
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 Cal   BC04     BC04A   130
```

Here it keeps the "Site" values that are duplicated, calculates the mean of "Band1" and selects the first row per "Site".

Maybe you also want to bind the duplicated and non-duplicated rows:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Site) %>%
 filter(n() > 1) %>%
 mutate(Band1 = mean(Band1)) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 bind_rows(df %>%
            group_by(Site) %>%
            filter(n() < 1) %>%
            ungroup())
```

Or if you want to calculate it just from the duplicated values per "Site":

```
df %>%
 group_by(Site, dup = duplicated(Site)) %>%
 filter(dup) %>%
 mutate(Band1 = mean(Band1)) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-dup)

  Site  Location Line  Band1
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 Cal   BC04     BC04B   130
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: Is `filter(n()>1)` required?

Comment: @yarnabrina it makes sense not to calculate a mean from a single value.

Comment: In case there are no duplicates for some Site, it'll be filtered. Since mean of single value returns itself, then perhaps it'll make more sense. Of course, it depends on the context, and hence OP have to judge.

Comment: @yarnabrina for such a scenario, I included a solution where cases n > 1 and cases n < 1 are bind by rows.

Answer (score 1):

I like data.table for this

```
x <-data.frame( 
Site = c( "Cal","Cal","Cal"),
Location = c( "BC04","BC04","BC04"),
Line = c( "BC04A","BC04B","BC04C"),
Band1= c(130,131, 129))

library( data.table)
x<- data.table( x )

x[ , .(Band1=mean( Band1 )) , by = c("Site","Location")]
```